# Displaying errors on frontend profile form

Tags: error, frontend-form

I have a user profile form on the frontend that doesn't display errors for a URL field.
The field handle is 'website'.

This is my code:

```
{% macro errorList(errors) %}
{% if errors %}
    {{ ul(errors, {class: 'errors'}) }}
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
{% set user = user ?? currentUser %}

<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{ csrfInput() }}
  {{ actionInput('users/save-user') }}
  {{ hiddenInput('userId', user.id) }}
  {{ redirectInput("members/my-profile") }}    
  {% if user.hasErrors() %}
    <p><b class="error">The profile could not be saved</b></p>
  {% endif %}
     
  <input type="text" id="first-name" class="" name="fields[firstNameEnglish]" value="{{ user.firstNameEnglish }}" placeholder="First Name" autocomplete="given-name">   
  <input type="text" id="last-name" class="" name="fields[lastNameEnglish]" value="{{ user.lastNameEnglish }}" placeholder="Last Name" autocomplete="family-name">
  {% if user.hasErrors('website') %}<p><b class="error">Invalid URL</b></p>{% endif %}
  <input type="text" id="website" class="{{ user.hasErrors('website') ? 'error'}}" name="fields[website]" value="{{ user.website }}">
  <button type="submit">Save Profile</button>
  <a href="/en/members/my-profile">Cancel</a>
</form>
```

When I save the form with an invalid URL, the page reloads, all the other field are empty again and there is not error message. What am I doing wrong?